# jQuery Isotope toggle content

Tags: javascript, jquery, sorting, jquery-isotope

I have a large selection of article headlines, each with a class name according to the source. When the site loads all headlines are displayed. The sources are listed at the top of the page and I would like Isotope to display or hide each one when clicked so users can choose their favourite sources.

As it stands I can remove them okay but I'm not sure how to get them to appear again.

```
jQuery(function($){
    var $container = $('.isotope-box');
    $container.isotope({
    masonry: {
        columnWidth: 333,
        cornerStampSelector: '.corner-stamp'
    },
    itemSelector: '#headlines'
});

// filter items when filter link is clicked
$('#filters a').click(function(){
    $(this).toggleClass("active");
    var selector = $(this).attr('data-filter');
    var $removable = $container.find( selector );
    $container.isotope( 'remove', $removable );
    jQEvent.preventDefault();
});

$('#filters a.active').click(function(){
    $(this).toggleClass("active");
    var selector = $(this).attr('data-filter');
    var $addition = $container.find( selector );
    $container.isotope( 'insert', $addition );
    jQEvent.preventDefault();
    });
});
```

I'm guessing the problem is with my 'insert' code but I'm not sure how that is supposed to work. I'm also using Infinite Scroll and I need the newly added pages to be displayed using the same filters.

Please help!

Martyn

Comment: I have created categories. So when I need to show all, I filter using *. Otherwise by specific filter.

Answer (score 0):

You could just filter out the unwanted Isotope elements, no? The filtering classes would be your sources (nyt, wsj, wp, ...). If you .remove() them, you remove them from the DOM for good! See [the filtering documentation](http://isotope.metafizzy.co/docs/filtering.html) but maybe I did not quite get your question?